# Start Motion with -m command line option

Tags: motion

I am using Motion as a basic IP camera so to lighten the load I would like to start the service with motion detection paused. From the documentation in need to add -m to the parameters when running motion. However as this is started as a service if I add the -m option the the script that init.d calls to start motion it fails to start, I had a look at the log files but I'm not that savvy with browsing log files and couldn't find anything relevant, advice welcome.

I have a workaround as a cron task every 5 minutes that calls the URL to pauses motion detection but this doesn't seem like the best way.

So, is there a way to start the motion service with motion detection paused? Alternatively is there a way to simply stream a USB camera as a basic IP camera?

Comment: Not an answer (as its just links) but have a look at https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org and https://hackaday.com/2017/09/12/video-streaming-like-your-raspberry-pi-depended-on-it/

Comment: Also init.d is out https://thepracticalsysadmin.com/intro-to-systemd/ is in :-)